# How to use a ProgressDialog properly with an AsyncTask without causing window leaks?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have an AsyncTask which shows a ProgressDialog. The AsyncTask is started when the activity is started:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_layout);
        new MyTask().execute();
    }

    // ... other code

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            // get data from a server
            return null;
        }    

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            // call to a method in MyActivity which updates the UI.
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly, untill I rotate my screen. Which makes sense, because the context that was used to create the dialog doesn't exist anymore (because the activity is re-created when rotating), and a window leak is caused.

The only solution I could think of isn't a really nice one: create a static instance of the task and dialog, and simply dismiss the dialog when the activity is destroyed, and recreate the dialog in the oncreate method if the task is still running.

So how would I solve something like this without losing functionality (so the dialog must always be shown when the task is running, and rotating the device should be allowed)?

Comment: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html. check the blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Raghunandan suggested in his comment, I looked into Fragments and solved my problem.

I created a Fragment which starts my AsyncTask, as explained in the [blogpost](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) that Raghunandan provided.

And to make sure that my Dialog didn't get leaked, I created a DialogFragment, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) (Basic Dialog).

Here's my working code:

My Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyTaskFragment.TaskCallbacks {
    private MyTaskFragment task;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_layout);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        task = (MyTaskFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("myTask");

        if (task == null) {
            task = new MyTaskFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(task, "myTask").commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myDialog");
        if (prev != null) {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        StringProgressDialogFragment dialog = StringProgressDialogFragment.newInstance("My message");
        dialog.show(ft, "myDialog");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute() {
        StringProgressDialogFragment dialog = (StringProgressDialogFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myDialog");
        if (dialog!=null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        // update UI
    }

    // ... other code
}
```

My Task fragment:

```
public class MyTaskFragment extends Fragment {
    private TaskCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private Task mTask;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mCallbacks = (TaskCallbacks) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Retain this fragment across configuration changes.
        setRetainInstance(true);

        // Create and execute the background task.
        mTask = new Task();
        mTask.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    private class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mCallbacks.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            // do stuff
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            mCallbacks.onPostExecute();
        }
    }

    public static interface TaskCallbacks {
        void onPreExecute();
        void onPostExecute();
    }
}
```

My Dialog fragment:

```
public class StringProgressDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private String message;

    public static StringProgressDialogFragment newInstance(String message) {
        StringProgressDialogFragment dialog = new StringProgressDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("message", message);
        dialog.setArguments(args);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        message = getArguments().getString("message");
        dialog.setMessage(message);
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with sample. it will work. basically just restrict the oncreate call by handling the config change. this solution may help you.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {


LoadProgrssdata task = new LoadProgrssdata();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(this, "oncreate called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        task.execute();
}

public class LoadProgrssdata extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    //declare other objects as per your need
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Progress Dialog Title Text","Process Description Text", true);

        //do initialization of required objects objects here                
    };      
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {   

         //do loading operation here  

        try {
            Thread.sleep(6000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }       
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    };
 }

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

        Log.e("orientation ", "landscape");

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

        Log.e("orientation ", "portrait");
    }
}
 }
```

and in android manifest file:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  
       android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
```

Answer (score 0):

New Loaders API can help you (available via support package) - [man](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html). They will solve problem with rotation, but not a mem. leak. To solve mem. leaks write your own "AsyncTask" (with a "clearContext" routine) and clear it's context in activity's onDestroy (or onPause, depends on your architecture). It may looks like a bicycle, but the task takes max 1 day, and you will have a full control on all the resources you background worker use.

By the way: consider using dialogs through fragments, because it solves dialog kill on screen rotation.

Comment: Custom AsyncTask, also can be made of Aysnctask  sources - they are not so huge.

Comment: It wasn't a mem. leak, but a android.view.WindowLeaked exception.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this problem by trying to catch any crash that, may occurs, in doInBackground.